# Twitter OAuth - Invalid or expired access token

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am trying to share post using **[twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth-demo)** with latest version. Below is my code.

```
require APP."Vendor/twitteroauth-master/autoload.php"; // twitter v0.5.1 SDK

if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])) {

        $request_token = [];
        $request_token['oauth_token'] = $this->Session->read('twtr_oauth_token');
        $request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $this->Session->read('twtr_oauth_token_secret');

        /* If denied, bail. */
        if (isset($_REQUEST['denied'])) {
            exit('Permission was denied. Please start over.');
        }

        /* If the oauth_token is not what we expect, bail. */
        if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
            $this->Session->write("twtr_oauth_token" , '');
            $this->Session->write("twtr_oauth_token_secret" , '');
            exit;
        }

        debug($request_token);

        /* Create TwitteroAuth object with app key/secret and token key/secret from default phase */
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth("KEY", "SECRET", $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

        debug($connection);

        $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

        debug($content);

        /* Request access token from twitter */
        $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));

        /** Finally post things */
        $result = $connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => "hello world"));

        if(isset($result->errors) && count($result->errors) > 0) {
            debug($connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => "hello world")));
            exit;
        }

        $this->redirect("http://twitter.com");

    } else {

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth("KEY", "SECRET");

        /** Get Temp Token */
        $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => "https://180.211.99.162:9051/widgetapi/twitterOauth"));

        switch ($connection->getLastHttpCode()) {
            case 200:
                /** Write OAuth token and secret into session */
                $this->Session->write("twtr_oauth_token" , $request_token['oauth_token']);
                $this->Session->write("twtr_oauth_token_secret" , $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

                /** Build Auth URL */
                $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));

                /** Redirect */
                $this->redirect($url);
                break;
            default:
                /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
                echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
        }
    }
```

When I try to achieve this I get invalid or expired access token.

> **Debug information**

```
    /app/Controller/WidgetapiController.php (line 258)
array(
    'oauth_token' => 'AU549WSBbnxvibRcU5jzUzOwFAoUiTXs',
    'oauth_token_secret' => 'NRmkbByjjAPGQLJK06DaUauYfa38kpY6'
)
/app/Controller/WidgetapiController.php (line 261)
object(Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth) {
    [protected] timeout => (int) 5
    [protected] connectionTimeout => (int) 5
    [protected] decodeJsonAsArray => false
    [protected] userAgent => 'TwitterOAuth (+https://twitteroauth.com)'
    [protected] proxy => array()
    [private] response => object(Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Response) {
        [private] apiPath => null
        [private] httpCode => (int) 0
        [private] headers => array()
        [private] body => array()
        [private] xHeaders => array()
    }
    [private] bearer => null
    [private] consumer => object(Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Consumer) {
        key => 'KEY'
        secret => 'SECRET'
        callbackUrl => null
    }
    [private] token => object(Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Token) {
        key => 'AU549WSBbnxvibRcU5jzUzOwFAoUiTXs'
        secret => 'NRmkbByjjAPGQLJK06DaUauYfa38kpY6'
    }
    [private] signatureMethod => object(Abraham\TwitterOAuth\HmacSha1) {

    }
}
/app/Controller/WidgetapiController.php (line 263)
object(stdClass) {
    errors => array(
        (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
            code => (int) 89
            message => 'Invalid or expired token.'
        }
    )
}
/app/Controller/WidgetapiController.php (line 271)
object(stdClass) {
    errors => array(
        (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
            code => (int) 89
            message => 'Invalid or expired token.'
        }
    )
}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue! Any idea whats wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once you got callback, **initialize class again with new access token**

```
/* Request access token from twitter */
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));

$connection = new TwitterOAuth("KEY", "SECRET", $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
```

Comment: for me i gave oauth_token too. to make it work in line

$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'], "oauth_token"=> $oauth_token));

Comment: Was a nightmare to figure out bearer tokens with this library considering there is no docs on it. Thanks to this answer, i was able to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Using the latest version of [TwitterOAuth](https://twitteroauth.com/), and with help from @user3989103's answer in this thread and https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-oauth-verifier-does-not-always-work/31672, what worked for me was:

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($key, $secret, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);

$access_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'], 'oauth_token'=> $_REQUEST['oauth_token']));

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($key, $secret, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

$credentials = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```